# como tirar um unico texto de uma linha especifica num arquivo txt python

Tags: python, python-3.x, arquivo, txt

Estou fazendo um mini sistema para cadastrar produtos e alterar suas quantidades, mas estou lidando com um problema de apagar em uma certa linha uma parte do texto, por exemplo: '00000 1' para '00000 4'(código do produto e sua quantidade!).
Irei deixar o código com uma linha marcada para entenderem melhor.

```
from random import randint

while True:
    print('1 - ver lista de produtos\n2 - alterar quantidade\n3 - adicionar produto')
    opcao = int(input('opção: '))
    if opcao == 1:
        with open('NAME', 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:
            for i in f:
                print(i)

    elif opcao == 2:
        produto = input('qual o codigo do produto?\n>')
        with open('NAME', 'rt+', encoding="utf8") as f:
            for i in f:
                if i[:5] == produto:
                    print(f'a quantidade do produto é: {i[6:]}')
                    qtd = str(input('para quantos deseja alterar?\n>'))

                    # é aqui onde eu preciso colocar o código mas não sei como faço ele

                else:
                    continue

    elif opcao == 3:
        a = randint(10000, 99999)
        print(f'o código do produto é: {a}')
        with open('NAME', 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:
            for i in f:
                if i[:5] == a:
                    a = randint(10000, 99999)
                else:
                    pass
            quantidade = int(input('qual a quantidade do produto?\n>'))
        open('NAME', 'at+').write(f'{a} ')
        open('NAME', 'at+').write(f'{quantidade}')
        open('NAME', 'at+').write('\n')

    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução possível abaixo:

```
from random import randint

while True:
    print('1 - ver lista de produtos\n2 - alterar quantidade\n3 - adicionar produto')
    opcao = int(input('opção: '))
    if opcao == 1:
        with open('NAME', 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:
            for i in f:
                print(i)

    elif opcao == 2:
        produto = input('qual o codigo do produto?\n>')
        with open('NAME', 'rt+', encoding="utf8") as f:
            # Lê todas as linhas do arquivo de antemão
            linhas = f.readlines() 
            for indice, linha in enumerate(linhas): 
                if linha[:5] == produto:
                    print(f'a quantidade do produto é: {linha[6:]}')
                    qtd = str(input('para quantos deseja alterar?\n>'))

                    # Apenas linha = f'{linha[:5]} {qtd}\n' não modificaria a lista
                    linhas[indice] = f'{linha[:5]} {qtd}\n'

                else:
                    continue
            # Reposiciona o ponteiro do arquivo pro início dele. Caso contrário estaria escrevendo as linhas ao final dele
            f.seek(0)
            f.writelines(linhas)

    elif opcao == 3:
        a = randint(10000, 99999)
        print(f'o código do produto é: {a}')
        with open('NAME', 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:
            for i in f:
                if i[:5] == a:
                    a = randint(10000, 99999)
                else:
                    pass
            quantidade = int(input('qual a quantidade do produto?\n>'))
        open('NAME', 'at+').write(f'{a} ')
        open('NAME', 'at+').write(f'{quantidade}')
        open('NAME', 'at+').write('\n')

    else:
        pass
```

Não é a solução mais rápida, pois escreve o arquivo inteiro novamente.

Comment: Muito obrigado cara você me ajudou muito, o código funciona sim, eu tinha pensado nisso mas não fazia ideia de como fazer então acabei desistindo dessa opção, mas obrigado!